# SharePoint online: Error 503 in BCS service

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I want to integrate data from WCF service into my SharePoint Online tenant. For this I have created BDC Model to import in BCS service.

I followed below steps,

1. Open SharePoint admin center
2. Go to Classic features and open BCS
3. service Click on 'Manage BDC Models and External Content Types'
4. Select 'BDC Model' in ribbon and click import

After this it is giving me Error

> 503 SERVICE UNAVAILABLE

.

What could be the reason for this, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, you can check the status of this issue via Office 365 Admin Center-> Health -> Service health->Advisories->SharePoint Online:

[image]

For this issue, I suggest you wait for the fix.

Comment: Its strange I checked now and I don't see this advisory in my tenant. Could it have been resolved? But I am still facing error 503 while importing BDC model.